# How can I grep a string with brackets and quotes?

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to grep the following in my directory:

```
$form['#submit'][1]
```

I've tried various permutations possible of escaping characters, including:

```
grep -r "$form\['#submit'\]\[1\]" ./*
grep -r "$form\['#submit']\[1]" ./*
grep -r "$form\['#submit']\[1]" *
grep -r "$form\['#submit'][1]" *
grep -r "$form\[\'#submit'][1]" *
grep -r "$form\[\'#submit']\[1]" *
grep -r "$form\[\'#submit\']\[1]" *
grep -r "$form\[\'#submit\'\]\[1\]" *
grep -r "\$form\[\'#submit\'\]\[1\]" *
grep -r "$form\[\'#submit\'\]\[1\]" *
grep -r "$form['#submit'][1]" ./*
```

But nothing seems to be getting the correct terms. How do I grep this expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**About escaping**

Basically you just need to escape the characters which have a meaning in basix posix regexes, which are:

- `$` End of line
- `[` Start of character class
- `]` End of character class

Additionally you need to use double quotes to enclose the pattern since it contains single quotes itself. But in this case you need to double escape the `$` since it has a meaning when inside shell's double quotes (start of variable) *and* the regex pattern (end of line).

```
grep -r "\\$form\['#submit'\]\[1\]"
```

**About fixed strings instead of patterns**

On the other hand you need to know that grep is also able to search for fixed strings instead of regex patterns. You need to pass `-F` in that case:

```
grep -rF "\$form['#submit'][1]"
```

Now, only the `$` needs to be escaped since bash would otherwise try to expand the subsequent characters as a variable name.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to avoid excessive escaping use `-F` option for fixed string search:

```
grep -riF "\$form['#submit'][1]" .
```

`$` still needs to be escape since whole string is in double quotes.

Comment: Plus one for  `-F`! (again! I forgot!) :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote `$` `[` and `]`

**Test**

```
$ cat input
$form['#submit'][1]

$ grep "\$form\['#submit'\]\[1\]" input
$form['#submit'][1]
```

**Why ?**

- `$` To escape the special meaning of `$` in bash/shell and prevent variable expansion
- `[` and `]` Escape the special meaning of `[` of character class

**Shorter method**

```
$ grep "\$form\['#submit']\[1]" input
$form['#submit'][1]
```

Here only the opening `[` is escaped which causes any occurence of lone `]` to be treated as normal characters without special meaning